# 'ListingGenerator' object is not iterable using ASYNCPRAW

Tags: python, discord.py, reddit, praw

I want to get memes from a subreddit. The issue is when I try to get the memes using the method `subreddit('memes')` the method returns a 'ListingGenerator'object which is not iterable.

I wanted to know if there is any way to convert this into a iterable object or any other method to get memes from reddit using ASYNCPRAW.

Here's the function:

```
    async def meme(self, ctx):
    subreddit = await  reddit.subreddit('memes')
    print(type(subreddit))
    all_subs = []
    print(subreddit.hot(limit=50))
    for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=50):
        all_subs.append(submission)
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    embed = discord.Embed(title=name)
    embed.set_image(url=url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ansel\PycharmProjects\Transfer News\cogs\meme.py", line 48, in meme
    for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=50):
TypeError: 'ListingGenerator' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\ansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'ListingGenerator' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `meme` command you are using a `for` loop to iterate the returned `ListingGenerator`, which is an *async source*. In this case you will need to use an `async for` loop to be able to iterate an *async source*.

Using a normal `for` loop you are not allowed to iterate over an *async source* unless you try blocking the event loop, because `for` calls `__next__` as a blocking function and does not await its result.

There are some [examples](https://apraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/models/subreddit/subreddit.html#) of how to iterate over the returned `ListingGenerators` in [**APRAW** documentation](https://apraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

#### References:

- [Subreddit](https://apraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/models/subreddit/subreddit.html#)
- [ListingGenerator](https://apraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/models/listing.html)

Comment: Yup thanks for pointing it out. Another thing is that after adding `async` it still had an error and so I had to not pass the `username` and `password` variables in the function `asyncpraw.Reddit()`(Even though in the documentation it says otherwise).